# how can i keep saved files in a cell everytime i upload a new file? am using laravel 5.5

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I created a user table with employee's details, and in my image column I have a file uploaded in its cell. How can I keep old file every time I upload a new file.
my view.blade

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $employee['image'] }}" multiple>

<th> <a href="{{ url('/people/employees/download/' . $employee['image']) }}">{{$employee['image']}}</a></th>
```

my controller

```
if($request->hasfile('image')){
$files = [];
        foreach ($request->image as $image) {
            $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = time() . '-' . $path;
            $files[] = $filename;
            $image->storeAs('employees', $employee->id . '/' . $filename);
            $image->move(public_path('employees'),$filename);
        }
        $files = implode("</br>;", $files);
    }
    $employee->image = $files;
    $employee->save();
```

Comment: what does cell mean here, you question is not that clear

Comment: Try with change the line `$employee->image = $files;` to `$employee->image =  $employee->image  .  $files;`

Comment: where data is stored @bhucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change one line :

```
$employee->image = $files;
```

to,

```
$employee->image = $employee->image . $files;
```